# PL SQL xmlelement: How to get data in xml from mutually exclusive condition on same tables

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I was fetching some data from database using XML . Here is my  tables:

Settings Table:

```
class   code    name
'm1'    1       Food1
'm1'    2       Food2
'p1'    1       PayInCash
'p2'    2       PayOnline

Customer Table:
customer_id  food_name  payment_method
CUS123          1         1 
CUS123          2         2
```

As you can see, that i have used some internal codes to map with its detail

I want to write the query that will give the following output:

```
Query Output:
customer_id  food_name  payment_method
CUS123          Food1      PayInCash 
CUS123          Food2      PayOnline
```

I want to retrieve the data in XML format,that's why i am using xmlelement.

```
SELECT xmlelement("customer_records",
                   XMLAGG(
                        xmlelement("record",
                            xmlelement("cus_id", customer_id),
                            xmlelement("food", food_name),
                            xmlelement("payment", payment_method)
                        )
                    )
             )

            FROM Customer 
            WHERE customer_id = 'CUS123';
```

You can see that i can't do join because of because conditions.
Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dependent subqueries, in this way:

```
SELECT customer_id,
       ( SELECT name FROM Settings s
         WHERE class LIKE 'm%' AND s.code = c.food_name ) AS food_name,
       ( SELECT name FROM Settings s
         WHERE class LIKE 'p%' AND s.code = c.payment_method ) AS payment_method 
FROM customer c;
```

---

Example using XMLAGG:

```
SELECT xmlelement("customer_records",
                   XMLAGG(
                        xmlelement("record",
                            xmlelement("cus_id", customer_id),
                            xmlelement("food", food_name),
                            xmlelement("payment", payment_method)
                        )
                    )
             )
FROM (
      SELECT customer_id,
             ( SELECT name FROM Settings s
               WHERE class LIKE 'm%' AND s.code = c.food_name ) AS food_name,
             ( SELECT name FROM Settings s
               WHERE class LIKE 'p%' AND s.code = c.payment_method ) AS payment_method 
      FROM customer c
);
```

Result:

```
<customer_records>
    <record>
        <cus_id>CUS123</cus_id>
        <food>Food1</food>
        <payment>PayInCash</payment>
    </record>
    <record>
        <cus_id>CUS123</cus_id>
        <food>Food2</food>
        <payment>PayOnline</payment>
    </record>
</customer_records>
```